# Google Apps Script Latest Form Responses to be triggered -

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking at having automated emails trigger on submission of a google form. It is working fine, however, I want only the latest response to be triggered. Instead, it runs through the entire sheet again. Any help will be much appreciated

```
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[5];  // First column
    var message = 'Hello,'+ "\n"
                   +  "\n" 
                   + 'We have received an inquiry from your customer in Inbound'+ ".\n"
                   + "\n"
                   + 'Lead No is' + " - " 
                   +  row[1] + "\n"
                   +  "\n"
                   + 'Kindly arrange a callback'+ "\n"
                   + "\n"
                   + 'Regards,'+ "\n"
                   + 'Team Inbound'; // Second column
    var emailSent = row[7];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Inbound Inquiry"+ " - " + row[1];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly, the code runs through all the sheet because this line of code

`var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());`

has a range from the first row to the last one. If you want to get only the last row, change it to:

`var dataRange = sheet.getRange(numRows, 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());`

Don't forget the `getRange()` format is `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns);`

More information [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).

Comment: Glad it did! Please, consider accepting my answer. Cheers :)